# Does Gitlab CI.yml take more resouce when pipelines are blocked than pipelines passed by "allow_failure = true"?

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci, cicd

I'm modifying .gitlab-ci.yml in my project, so that the rules of jobs can be clear.

I found that my jobs are set as manual in "rules" block,and didn't set allow_failure. According to the spec. ,the default value is **false**.

After I push new commit, those manual jobs are waiting manual start.And the pipeline will show "blocked".

However, if I set "allow_failure = TRUE",the result of pipeline would be "passed".

I'm wondering if the "blocked" status are still in the system,and takes more resource than "passed" status take.

Should I set allow_failure as true in manual jobs?

Comment: What do you mean by "still in the system"? Are you referring to the job, the recorded status of the job, or something else?

Comment: I mean that those manual jobs are waiting manual operations, so the status is "blocked", instead of "passed".

And if manual jobs(when allow_failure is set false) are waiting ,would they still use memory or other resource?

Comment: If yes, would manual jobs(when allow_failure is set false) take more resource than manual jobs(when allow_failure is set true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `blocked` [status](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#list-project-pipelines) (it called `manual` in the API) does not require any additional resources as well as `allow_failure:false`.

There are [two types](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#types-of-manual-jobs) of manual jobs: `optional` and `blocking`. `optional` jobs do not have to finish successfully to have pipeline finished with success. In turn `blocking` jobs must finish successfully to have pipeline finished with success.

The `blocked` status is used to show on the web UI that there are `blocked` manual jobs in the pipeline that have not yet been executed.